# Android printing Emojis using string

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I have a variable (emoji) that contains a string `\ud83d\ude03` which I have got from parsing an xml. They are emoticon encodings. The problem is when I try to print them in the following way :

```
editText.setText(emoji)
```

the output is `\ud83d\ude03`

However when I do this :

```
editText.setText("\ud83d\ude03")
```

the output is smiley. Is there any work around to this? I think the problem is that my backslash is getting escaped. I cant change the xml files and thus I've tried converting the strings in java itself with no avail.

Comment: When you say you've tried converting the strings in java, what have you tried, have you tried to replace all / with // ?

Comment: yes I had done that. I realized my string had an extra quotes attached to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
String smiley = "\ud83d\ude03";
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.setText(smiley);

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText(smiley);
```

Layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"/>
```

It works as you see. You error must be in `emoji` variable.

[image: Solution]

Comment: the problem was with the extra quotes in the variable. thank you

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answer(s) and choose the best answer `\ud83d\ude03`

Answer (score 0):

SO you're parsing xml and it sends down the string "\ud83d" as 6 characters?  Its doing what its supposed to.  If you want to fix this, you need to parse the string yourself and convert these sequences to the correct unicode points.  Or you need to have the server send down the unicode points rather than escape them.